# ¿Cómo llamar a una aplicación hecha en node.js (con base de datos o no) desde un alojamiento externo (tipo Heroku, Github) a una web/blog?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aplicación-web, heroku

Me refiero a cómo llamar a mi web/blog al/a los archivo/s de una aplicación o servicio hecho en node.js (tenga o no base de datos (sqlite, mongodb) y alojado en un servidor gratuito externo (como Heroku, etc.). Por ejemplo: un contenido relacionado de webs de terceros (cuyas urls están almacenadas), un buscador, etc.

Sería simplemente así:

```js
<script src="url desde heroku/app.js">
```

Comment: Lo planteo en el caso de que no se pueda poner node.js en un servidor compartido, sino llamarlo desde un alojamiento externo gratuito.

Comment: Puedes enviar una peticion ajax desde el sitio y devolver un json desde nodejs